# Issue with mysql node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, command-line

I have recently installed `MySQL` on my **Ubuntu 16.04**. And I have successfully been able to use commands in the command prompt to create tables, and do commands like

```
select * from articles
```

However, the issue appears when I run code from a `.js` file from `node.js`. The command line just freezes afterwards. In the picture below, the terminal on the right is the one calling the `select.js` file with node, while the one on the left is manually calling `select * from articles`:

[image]

Interestingly enough, when I use the `insert.js` file, the same thing happens in the terminal on the right **BUT** the line is inserted (which I can verify manually with the terminal on the left).

**QUESTION:**
Why might the terminal on the right not finish executing and in the case of the `select * from articles` not display the content inside the articles table?

Comment: can you please copy paste the code in your snapshot to a fiddle or on SO itself?

Comment: Please do not include images of text. Instead, copy the relevant text to the question. This increases searchability, protects against the image going away at some point, *and* allows others to help with your question since they can copy and paste if/when needed.

Comment: use `result` in your console log instead of `query.sql`

Comment: Oh so I used `result` and it does indeed output the resulting objects. Is the fact that the `root@goku-cp:home/goku/Desktop#` isn't automatically repearing a problem? and if it isn't, how might I make it automatically come back

Comment: try closing your database connection

Comment: thank you @GirdhariAgrawal problem solved !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you'r not closing db connection after select so there is something in event loop.

Add `connection.end();` after `console.log(query.sql);`
and `console.log(result);` to display results

Comment: I tried doing that however I get `TypeError: connection.close is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

Please use the `result` variable in the `callback` as well which gives you the exact response of query.

It should be like this

```
var query = connection.query(<sql query>, function (err, res){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
});
```